# C++ header and cpp file fpermisive

Tags: c++

I am really short on time and i can't figure out what I am doing wrong here.

I am trying to link 3 class object together but I keep getting error for everything and i can't find any answer on the internet.

I would like to know how to correctly make the .h and .cpp files.

Maybe some of you will see what I did wrong. I wish to separate the code by the way.

Edit1: 
This is the error i get, my bad: In file included from recette/ListeRecettes.cpp:8:0:
recette/ListeRecettes.h:23:42: erreur: ISO C++ forbids declaration of ‘ajouterRecette’ with no type [-fpermissive]

Edit2:  ISO C++ forbids declaration of ‘ajouterRecette’ with no type [-fpermissive] 
Same thing
Edit3: Sorry file name in comment where not right.

Here the Header

```
/* 
 * File:   ListeRecettes .h
 * Author: Necro
 *
 * Created on November 17, 2015, 1:51 PM
 */

#ifndef LISTERECETTES_H
#define LISTERECETTES_H

#include <vector>  //for std::vector
#include "iostream"
#include "Recette.h"


class ListeRecettes {
private:
    std::vector<Recette*> recettes;

public:
    ListeRecettes();
    ListeRecettes(const ListeRecettes& orig);
    void ajouterRecette(const Recette& recette);
    void enleverRecette(const Recette& recette);
    void afficher();
    virtual ~ListeRecettes();
};

#endif  /* RECETTES_H */
```

And here the .cpp

```
/* 
 * File:   ListeRecettes .cpp
 * Author: Necro
 * 
 * Created on November 17, 2015, 1:51 PM
 */

#include "ListeRecettes.h"
#include <vector>  //for std::vector
#include "iostream"

ListeRecettes::ListeRecettes() {
}

ListeRecettes::ListeRecettes(const ListeRecettes& orig) {
}

ListeRecettes::ajouterRecette(const Recette& recette) {
    this->recettes.push_back(recette);
}

ListeRecettes::enleverRecette(const Recette& recette) {
    for (int i = 0; i < recettes.size(); i++) {
        if (recettes.at(i).getNom() == recette.getNom()) {
            recettes.erase(i);
        }
    }
}

ListeRecettes::afficher(){
    for(int i = 0 ; i < recettes.size(); i ++){
        std::cout << recettes.at(i).getNom();
    }
}

ListeRecettes::~ListeRecettes() {
}
```

Edit4:
Recette.h

```
/* 
 * File:   Recette.h
 * Author: Necro
 *
 * Created on November 17, 2015, 3:14 PM
 */

#ifndef RECETTE_H
#define RECETTE_H

#include <vector>  //for std::vector
#include "Ingredient.h"
#include "iostream"

using namespace std;

class Recette {
public:
    Recette();
    Recette(const Recette& orig);
    Recette(string& , Ingredient&);
    string getNom();
    Ingredient getIngredient();
    virtual ~Recette();
private:
    string nom;
    vector<Ingredient*> listeIngredients;
};

#endif  /* RECETTE_H */
```

Recette.cpp

```
/* 
 * File:   Recette.cpp
 * Author: Necro
 * 
 * Created on November 17, 2015, 3:14 PM
 */

#include "Recette.h"
#include "iostream"

using namespace std;

Recette::Recette() {
}

Recette::Recette(string& nom, Ingredient ingredient) {
    this->nom = nom;
    this->listeIngredients.push_back(ingredient);
}

Recette::Recette(const Recette& orig) {
}

Recette::getNom(){
    return this->nom;
}
Recette::getIngredient(){
    return this->listeIngredients;
}

Recette::~Recette() {
}
```

Ingredient.h

```
/* 
 * File:   Ingredient.h
 * Author: Necro
 *
 * Created on November 17, 2015, 2:18 PM
 */

#ifndef INGREDIENT_H
#define INGREDIENT_H

#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class Ingredient {


public:
    Ingredient();
    Ingredient(string&,int);
    Ingredient(const Ingredient& orig);
    void addIngredient(int quantite);
    void removeIngredient(int quantite);
    virtual ~Ingredient();

private:
    string nom;
    int quantite;
};



#endif  /* INGREDIENT_H */
```

Ingredient.cpp

```
/* 
 * File:   Ingredient.cpp
 * Author: Necro
 * 
 * Created on November 17, 2015, 2:18 PM
 */

#include "Ingredient.h"

Ingredient::Ingredient() {
}

Ingredient::Ingredient(string &nom, int quantite) :
nom(nom), quantite(quantite) {
    this->nom = nom;
    this->quantite = quantite;
}

Ingredient::Ingredient(const Ingredient& orig) {
}

Ingredient::addIngredient(int quantite) {
    this->quantite += quantite;
}
Ingredient::removeIngredient(int quantite){
    this->quantite -= quantite;
}

Ingredient::~Ingredient() {
}
```

Comment: You keep getting *what* error?

Comment: I did an edit sorry about that

Comment: why include `Recette.h` in itself?

Comment: and you included `ListeRecettes.h` but you have `Recettes.h`

Comment: Actually it was netbean who did the import for this one. But Recette is not the same thing, Recette.h is an other Class

Comment: Because i did not correct the comment file name, The right file name is ListeRecettes .h and ListeRecettes .cpp

Comment: you also have to edit the .cpp file for example `void ListeRecettes::ajouterRecette`

Comment: you should add the return type in both Recette.h and Recette.cpp file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your signatures are definitely wrong.

You have to define the return type every except for the constructor and the destructor.

so something like this:

```
void ajouterRecette(const Recette& recette);
void enleverRecette(const Recette& recette);
void afficher();
```

Then update the cpp accordingly.

Then you can post the errors!

Comment: It does the same thing :S

Comment: Update the cpp accordingly.  Add "void" to the beginning of method implementations in the cpp.

Comment: Thank you I now have some bug to correct.